# I would like a new text box comes out when someone clicks on others

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in access that dropdown box. Now what I want is when someone choose others from the dropdown box, a new text box shows up to allow the user to type. Anyone help please thank y ou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DropDown is called Combo1 and on the same form you have a textbox called Text1 and the value of "Others" is also "others". Then you just need to code the Combo1's Change event like so

```
Private Sub Combo1_Change()

        Me.Text1.Visible = (Me.Combo1.Value = "others")        

End Sub
```